# Import-Csv $File | Select not working

Tags: csv, powershell

I have `$ADPcsv = Import-Csv "C:\myfile.csv"` with many headers that have spaces. Looking at the array works and I can see all the data. But when I try to select only a few columns, I get nothing. Is my syntax wrong?

```
$mytable = ($ADPcsv | select "St Identification SID","Position ID","Reports To Position ID","Reports To Last Name","Reports To First Name")
```

I want to then create a hashtable, but whenever I try to look at the data, it's always empty. Looking at the array `$mytable` lists only the headers over and over and none of the data from the CSV.

Comment: do you get what you expect with this? `$adpcsv.gettype()` or this? `$adpcsv.count` or `$adpcsv[0] | fl *`

Comment: Yes, they both say system.array but only the $ADPcsv holds data. I thought that $mytable would hold a subset?

Comment: It looks like it should work. Can you provide some example content for the CSV so we can test? Are you running on an ancient version? Do you get column data out if you do something like `$ADPcsv | foreach { $_."St Identification SID; $_."Position ID" }` ?

Comment: It's working now. I think I may have forgotten to include the empty placeholder. But this works; $PIDTable = @{}

 Import-csv $ADPcsv | ForEach-Object {
    $PIDTable[$_.'Position ID'] = $_
}